# NoReverseMatch exception in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I've got this urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

                   # Plugin actions
                   url(r'plugin/((?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/)?$', PluginView.as_view(), name='wa-plugin'),
                   )
```

Then when I use reverse :

```
reverse('wa-plugin', args=[u'plugin-header-1'])
```

or even

```
reverse('wa-plugin', kwargs={'slug':u'plugin-header-1'})
```

I get

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'wa-plugin' with arguments 
'('plugin-header-1',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Do you have any ideas of how I can make it works ?

Comment: well `slug` is a kwarg so the `args` version won't work. are you able to browse to the url you are trying to reverse? (i.e. does your regex definitely work)

Comment: Yes the url works, but it seams that reverse doesn't like the optionnal attribute in url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the problem is the optional argument, one way around that is to define two url entries (to the same view):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Plugin actions
    url(r'plugin/$', PluginView.as_view(), name='wa-plugin'),
    url(r'plugin/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/$', PluginView.as_view(), name='wa-plugin'),
)
```

(pretty sure you can even use the same name, since they have different "signatures (kwargs)")

Answer (score 0):

It seams that reverse doesn't like the optional arguments.

You should use :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

                   # Plugin actions
                   url(r'plugin/$', PluginView.as_view(), name='wa-plugin'),
                   url(r'plugin/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/$', PluginView.as_view(), name='wa-plugin-slug'),
                   )
```

Then `reverse` works both with `args` and `kwargs`